# How do I bind the value of my Entry to my ViewModel.cs?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Hey I am very new with Xamarin and I want to start with a simple method that has 3 Entry which will be read in a function "CalculateAv(Entry1, Entry2, Entry3)" that calculates the Average of the 3 entered numbers.
Somehow the entry in the parameters are undefined, probably bc the binding didnt worked out well. Here some code:
**BasicButtonCommandPage.xaml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ButtonDemos;assembly=ButtonDemos"
             x:Class="ButtonDemos.BasicButtonCommandPage"
             Title="Basic Button Command">

    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <local:CommandDemoViewModel />
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>

    <ContentPage.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <local:CommandDemoViewModel x:Key="model" />
            <local:DoubleToStringConverter x:Key="stringConverter" />
            <local:DoubleRoundingConverter x:Key="roundConverter" />
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </ContentPage.Resources>


    <StackLayout>
        <Label x:Name="Ausgabe" 
               Text="{Binding Number, StringFormat='Value is now {0}'}"
               FontSize="Large"
               VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" 
               HorizontalOptions="Center" />


        <Entry x:Name="Number1"
                Placeholder="Number1"
                Keyboard="Numeric"
                BindingContext="{x:Reference Rechner}" 
                Text="{Binding Path=CommanDemoViewModelProperty[modal].ErsteNummer}" />

        <Entry x:Name="Number2"
                Placeholder="Number2"
                Keyboard="Numeric"
                BindingContext="{x:Reference Rechner}"
                Text="{Binding Path=CommanDemoViewModelProperty[modal].ZweiteNummer}" />

        <Entry x:Name="Number3"
                Placeholder="Number3"
                Keyboard="Numeric"
                BindingContext="{x:Reference Rechner}"
                Text="{Binding Path=CommanDemoViewModelProperty[modal].DritteNummer}" />

        <Button x:Name="Rechner"
                Text="Multiply by 2"
                VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                HorizontalOptions="Center"
                Command="{Binding MultiplyBy2Command}" />
                <!--CommandParameter="{Binding Number1, Number2, Number3}" />-->


        <Button Text="Divide by 2"
                VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                HorizontalOptions="Center"
                Command="{Binding DivideBy2Command}" />
    </StackLayout>

</ContentPage>
```

**Here the CommanDemoViewModel.cs**

```
namespace ButtonDemos
{   

    class CommandDemoViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {

        double number = 2;
        double ersteNummer, zweiteNummer, dritteNummer;

        BindableProperty.Create()
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public double ErsteNummer
        {
            set
            {
                if (ersteNummer != value)
                {
                    ersteNummer = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("ErsteNummer");
                }
            }
            get
            {
                return ersteNummer;
            }
        }
        public double ZweiteNummer
        {
            set
            {
                if (zweiteNummer != value)
                {
                    zweiteNummer = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("ZweiteNummer");
                }
            }
            get
            {
                return zweiteNummer;
            }
        }
        public double DritteNummer
        {
            set
            {
                if (dritteNummer != value)
                {
                    dritteNummer = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("DritteNummer");
                }
            }
            get
            {
                return dritteNummer;
            }
        }
        public double Number
        {
            set
            {
                if (number != value)
                {
                    number = value;
                    PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Number"));
                }
            }
            get
            {
                return number;
            }
        }

        protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }

        void CalculateAv(double ersteNummer, double zweiteNummer, double dritteNummer)
        {
            List<double> grades = new List<double> { ersteNummer, zweiteNummer, dritteNummer };
            Number = grades.Average();
        }
        public CommandDemoViewModel()
        {


            MultiplyBy2Command = new Command(

       execute: () => CalculateAv(ersteNummer, zweiteNummer, dritteNummer));




        DivideBy2Command = new Command(() => Number /= 2);  
        }

        public ICommand MultiplyBy2Command { private set; get; }

        public List<int> grades { get; set; }
        public ICommand DivideBy2Command { private set; get; }
        public string Path { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Please dont get irritated by the button's name as it is a sample from xamarin.forms. Thank you all in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your binding is wrong, but that's pretty normal when starting with MVVM.

First, I'm not sure about your implementation of your ViewModel. Download the NuGet package [Xamarin.Common.Mvvm](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Common.Mvvm) and inherit your ViewModel from **BindableBase** (or just find some implentation of it, it's pretty easy to find).

Then, on your properties, change them for something like this property:

```
private int _myNumber;
public int MyNumber { get => _myNumber; set => SetProperty(ref _myNumber, value); }
```

The **SetProperty** method will be inherited from BindableBase, and will automatically raise property changed.

Now, in your XAML, the main problem is that you're setting the BindingContext for your entries twice: first in the beginning of the page, second in the entries. You can't do that, your controls may have only one context, and generally it is the page context. So, just set your ViewModel to the BindingContext of the page, and your others controls will use it.

After that, just set the Text properties of your entries for something like this:

```
Text="{Binding MyNumber}"
```

In theory, it should be working now. Any doubts just ask.

Comment: omg thank you so much! I just deleted the bindingContext in my entries and it worked!!!

Answer (score 2):

Your entries bindings are incorrect.

Number1 should appear as followed

```
Text="{Binding ErsteNummer, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

Comment: Thank you for your help I have corrected it. But it is still not working :/